# Autopilot and decimal truncation

Tags: twilio

I created an autopilot task that is trained like this:

Give

Give {amount}

The amount variable is a Twilio.NUMBER field type.

So if I send GIVE 100.76 it ends up returning 100.00 (truncating the amount after the decimal). Here's what data returned looks like:

[image]

Note the last value is just 100. I also created a Twilio Function that does something similar, and that retains the decimals. The snippet from that function is:

```
response.actions.push({ "collect": {
            "name": "gift_amount",
            "questions": [
                {
                    "question": "How much would you like to give?",
                    "name": "gift_amount",
                    "type": "Twilio.NUMBER"
                }
            ],
```

UPDATE: The issue was fixed, but it looks like the fix was reverted, as it is truncating again. The concerning thing is we did a couple tests with decimals and instead of just truncating, it removed the decimal altogether.  So GIVE .5 was seen as GIVE 5. Here's a screenshot from the query screen. Happened at 9:43 AM PST

[image]

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. We took a look at this and have made an update. Can you build a new model and test this again?

Comment: It works now. Thanks!

Comment: @philnash Did you guys change something with this? It was working, but now it is back to truncating the decimals.  Also had a case where 123.45 was entered, and it treated it like 12345 which is a problem if we are dealing with dollar amounts.

Comment: Also see my update in the ticket

Comment: Hi Scott, I'm actually on holiday right now, so not checking in with work. I'd recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) about this and let them know what's happened so far. This is valuable feedback for the Autopilot team too, so it's important that we all pursue this. I'll try to follow up when I'm back next week too.